# How to get text from EditText as it displayed on the screen (with line wraps)

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline

How to get a text from a multi line EditText line by line as it displayed on the screen?

For example, if you insert long text in EditText **(without `\n`)** it will be displayed in few lines. How to know where system insert line wrap?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if using `EditText.getLayout()`:

```
String text = editText.getText().toString();
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i< editText.getLayout().getLinesCount(); i++) {
    lines.add(text.substring(editText.getLayout().getLineStart(i), 
             editText.getLayout().getLineEnd(i));
}
```

Also `EditText.getLayout()` has methods for returning size of line:

```
getLineWidth()
getLineBounds()
```